# Implement Ethereum test wallet support in Python

Tags: python, ethereum, etherscan

I'm new in cryptocurrency and i need Implement Ethereum test wallet support in python. 
I have a account on etherscan.io already and a can add 1 ETH to my test wallet by https://faucet.metamask.io/
How can I increase my python test wallet balance by a specific ETH value?

Comment: Do you have some code, please add it to your question.

Comment: I don't have a code

Comment: If you don't have code, then stackoverflow is not the place to ask this question I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain free test Ethers (ETH), you can use the Ropsten faucet.

Open MetaMask and click “buy” (or “deposit” if you are using an Apple computer). Click on “Get Ether”, this should open a page that allows you to request as many test Ethers as possible. It may take up to a few minutes until the test Ethers show up in your balance in MetaMask.

Comment: I can deposit only 1 Ether in one transaction. I need deposite specific value of Ether, for example 20 in one transaction. How do this?